# Efficiently serialize tensorflow graph / session to db?

Tags: python, serialization, machine-learning, tensorflow

From what I can tell, the `tf.train.Saver()` interface can only take a file-prefix as input, and tensorflow itself handles the serialization of a model directly to disk.

I'm interested in writing the current state of a `tensorflow` model to a PostgreSQL database, and have been looking into serializing the current state of a `tensorflow` object to a location in memory, so that I can save that serialized state to a PostgreSQL `BYTEA` column.  How might I go about doing this?

My current workaround involves allowing `tf.train.Saver()` to write to disk at a `tempfile` location, reading and serializing the contents of those files, then re-writing to those file locations and allowing `tf.train.Saver()` to read from them to load the graph in at inference time.